# GraqphQL - 'formatError' not returning error path or showing anything helpful

Tags: graphql

is formatError supposed to return the path of the error?

my errors all look like this:

```
 [UserInputError: Variable "$task_name" of required type "String!" was not provided.] {
  locations: [ { line: 1, column: 69 } ],
  path: undefined,
  extensions: { code: 'BAD_USER_INPUT', exception: { stacktrace: [Array] } }
```

the path is always undefined. And I don't know how to read 'locations' because I have lots of resolvers organized into many different files.

There has to be a better setup, but I haven't been able to find it!!

someone please help before I go crazy!!

here is my server setup:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    introspection: true,

    formatError: (err) => {
      const error = getErrorCode(err.message)

      console.log(err) // THIS LOGS WHATS ABOVE

      return { message: error.message, statusCode: error.statusCode }
    },

    csrfPrevention: true,
    cache: 'bounded',
    //return any info here that we need to access in our resolvers
    context: async ({ req, res }): Promise<GraphQLContext> => {
      const session = (await getSession({ req })) as Session //getSession returns session | null
      //and since GraphQLContext is our return type, we have to declare it the same way in that interface
      return { session, prisma, req }
    },
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true })
    ]
  })
```